# Replacing compute Shader by openCL kernel, o/p is pixelated & flickers, though values in o/p buffer matches

Tags: parallel-processing, opencl, shader, directx-11, compute-shader

I have an application which has different shaders in it , one of them is compute shader, which computes the light values in the scene, light values are calculated by an accumulation function written in the compute shader.

I have written a kernel openCL (.cl) similar to that of compute shader’s (.hlsl) file.

I have replaced the compute shader , by the openCL kernel,

I have same values in the output light buffer as that of outputted by the compute shader,

But the output looks pixelated and it flickers on screen, and the square box of the one small unit of the pixelated output, matches the work group size , of my kernel.

As the output light buffer ,(which I’m pretty sure that this is the only one output buffer), has same values as that of compute shader , I could not figure out where my program is failing.

Has anyone faced similar problem before ? Any hints or suggestions will be helpful.

Comment: Is your output to a GL texture? How do you synchronize CL and GL?

Comment: its DirectX3d 11 and CL , I call kernel for each DXUT loop's render

Comment: output buffer is a structured buffer in D3D

Comment: Do you call clFinish after clEnqueueReleaseD3D...?

Comment: As I'm using D3D 11 , I'm not using clEnqueueReleaseD3D , I'm creating staging buffers , copying resource from from shader graphics pipeline restricted buffers to staging buffers, mapping those, and and from their mapped data's pointer I'm creating cl buffers , and passing those as cl_mem to kernel, I'm calling cl_finish , before releasing any argument's memory passed to cl kernel.

Comment: I see. If you created your OpenCL buffers with USE_HOST_PTR, then you will need a blocking enqueueMapBuffer to ensure the buffer bits are moved back to host memory.

Comment: Yes I have created with CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR | CL_MEM_READ_WRITE , and I'm doing blocking clEnqueueMapBuffer after cl_finish . It gives same results , The light values in the output are not blended properly , in one iteration a sqaure block takes one light , and another in another.